# mongoexport - Failed: Cursor not found

Tags: mongodb, cursor, mongoexport

I am trying to execute a `mongoexport` command as follows:

```
mongoexport -d db_foo -c col_bar -q '{"a": {"$in": ["pqr", "xyz"]}, "b": "bar", "c": /foo/i}' --fields "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n" --type=csv -o data/foo.csv
```

However, after a few minutes, the process exits and I get an error saying Cursor not found, as shown below:

```
2017-07-21T11:12:35.826+0530    connected to: localhost
2017-07-21T11:12:36.816+0530    rto_latest.wbn_data  0
...
2017-07-21T11:27:04.815+0530    rto_latest.wbn_data  224000
2017-07-21T11:27:04.864+0530    rto_latest.wbn_data  231530
2017-07-21T11:27:04.864+0530    Failed: Cursor not found, cursor id: 97340002510
```

Is there a [noCursorTimeout](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.noCursorTimeout/) option when using mongoexport in the command line? Else, how can I prevent this from happening?

I have MongoDB shell version v3.4.4

Edit:

The entire collection has ~35 million documents and ~3.2 million documents should be selected by this query.

Comment: That's not a lot of data for a 15 minute period of running. It would seem that a bigger issue here would be that the selection is taking a lot of time, and therefore you should look at making sure an index can satisfy the query issued. So if all you are getting after that period of time is 230K documents, then it would be likely no index is actually selected. You should probably also consider "breaking up" the ranges of the export if this is a particularly large dump.

Comment: In this case I should add "cl" as an index in that case?

Comment: Actually that is your biggest problem with the query. As a "case insensitive regular expression" this cannot actually use an index ( with the exception of where case insensitive collation is added using MongoDB 3.4). So really any index selection needs to happen on the other fields in the query. If however the best "limitter" is in fact on that field and regex match, then you have real problems and should look at using a set "lowercase" or "uppercase" version of that data. And in fact then either "anchor" to the start of the field or look for an "exact match" on the string instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn I'm relatively new to this, how should I go about doing what you suggest?

Comment: @IM94, Was this issue resolved from your side? How did you go about it?